# Laravel Eloquent query JSON column with Where In?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble querying a json column.

Previously my code was

```
$query->whereIn('user', $users);
```

Now i have changed the db type to JSON column and am trying to modify the code for the new version.

In RAW MYSQL this works

```
JSON_CONTAINS(user, '"tom","Bill"')
```

But when i put it in eloquent / php it keeps failing or returning noting. Here i am passing in an array of Users, previous using an WhereIn which works in raw SQL

```
$leads->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(user, '"$users"')")
```

Any idea how to make it work in Laravel so i can pass in an array of strings, query them against the json column which contains an array of strings too.

My Json colum has data like so

```
["Paul", "Tom", "Bob"]
```

Comment: Don't you need to add it like this? `$leads->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(user, '" .$users ."')")`

Comment: Just tied that there, gives a 500, the query executed is 

JSON_CONTAINS(user, 'Tom'') and it says Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Tom'')' at line 1

Comment: any ideas? i am really stuck with this

Answer (score 18):

MySQL expects a JSON string:

```
$leads->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(user, ?)', [json_encode($users)])
```

In Laravel 5.6.24 you can use `whereJsonContains()`:

```
$leads->whereJsonContains('user', $users)
```

Answer (score 3):

If `$users` is array of names then you should iterate over it and add `orWhereRaw` condition, note that [orWhereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) can accept an array of parameter:

```
 $users = ["Tom", "Bob"];

 foreach( $users as $user) {
      $leads->orWhereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(user, ?)", [$user]);
 }

 $leads = $leads->get();
```

Comment: When i run this i get back an empty array.

what is the ? for in this case?

Comment: `?` represent `$user` parameter, something like [PDO prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), you can't just concatenate `$user` in the `DB::raw` because of sql injection attacks

Comment: have you tried `$leads->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(user, ?)", [$users]);` with `$users = '"tom","Bill"'`

Comment: this sql works fine
      
     where  JSON_CONTAINS(user, '"Paul"')

But the code returns just an empty array

       foreach($users as $u){
                    $query->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(user, ?)", [$u]); 
                    die(var_dump($query->get()));
               }

Comment: You have to use `orWhereRaw` not `whereRaw` I think that's why you get empty array

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to use `whereRaw`. Assume `data` below is the `json` column:

```php
$categories = ['category-one', 'category-two', 'category-three'];

Article::where('published', true)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($categories) {

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $query->orWhereJsonContains('data->categories', $category);
        }
    })
    ->get();
```