# couldn't get data using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What I want is that when a user visits this link `/api/bonus?provider[]=MyCompany`
the result will show only bonus provided by providers=[MyCompany].

**In my controller:**

```
public function all(Request $request)
{
    $size = $request->input('size');

    $bonus = Bonus::with('category', 'bonus');
    $bonus = Filterer::apply($request, $size, $bonus);

 $bonus = Filterer::apply($request, $size, $bonus);

        return response()->json([
            'code' => 0,
            'success' => true,
            'data' => BonusResource::collection($bonus),
```

}

My expected result is to get all the providers that equal the `[MyCompany]`
But somehow this query doesn't work.

**Filterer**

```
public static function apply(Request $filters, $size, $bonus)
{
     if ($filters->has('provider')) {
                $bonus->whereHas('bonus', function ($query) use ($filters) {
                    $query->whereIn('providers', $filters->input('provider',[]));

                });
            }
return $bonus->paginate($size);
}
```

but at the end I'm getting this result. The data is null [].

[image]

I'm wonder why I can't get the data. Which part I had done wrong?

Comment: if you need more info please tell me

Comment: What is the rest of your code ? Because there, you seems to forgot the final `get()` or `count()` method to get datas

Comment: Is the provider only going to be a single provider at all times?  IE MyCompany?  If so, you can make the query simpler by just comparing `where('provider', $singleCompany)` or similar.  Also - suggest you change the bonus inside the function to a different variable like `$query`, as it may overlap.  Finally, as @bjovanov said, you have a query but no collection yet, as you aren't calling the final method to get the collection from the database.  Use `get()` to get all the bonus releases.  Maybe add a little more info on your question as to what you need (one company, many, etc).

Comment: Your controller function does not return anything.

Comment: @Watercayman Yes, I have a few provider's name, and I already change to variable to `$query` but still cannot get the result

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more info for people to help you.  'You cannot get the result'.  What does this mean - you get nothing when you dump the var?  At what point do you dump?  Or you don't get any results on the query, or?

Comment: @Watercayman question updated

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but based on your code, the function `apply` didn't return anything, it will always empty. Shouldn't it be return $bonus? and don't forget the `get`.

```
public static function apply(Request $filters, $size, $bonus)
{
     if ($filters->has('provider')) {
         $bonus->whereHas('bonusRelease', function ($bonus) use ($filters) {
             return $bonus->whereJsonContains('providers', $filters->input('provider',[]));
         });
     }
     return $bonus->get();
}
```

### Updated my answer

The `providers` is a json type. You can't just query it with `where in (a,b,c)`. Change to `whereJsonContains`. Please check this link [another case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188529/laravel-eloquent-query-json-column-with-where-in) and [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries).

Comment: Hi, check my updated answer @StackOverFlowSavedMyLife

Comment: sry to say that, but the result is still same, no data displayed

Comment: @StackOverFlowSavedMyLife make sure the `whereHas` function in `Filter` return the query too. I saw your code still not return anything. Check the relation if its not typo. And the filter is case sensitive.

Comment: In this line ` $bonus->whereHas('bonusRelease', function ($bonus) use ($filters)`
may I know the `function($bonus) use ($filters` refer to what? Cause what I read from docuemntation is whereHas('column', function(Builder $query){} which is different with yours

Comment: it can be dependency injection or parameter type to prevent random value (Check PSR). It doesn't make any differences. You should check on Closure in PHP. Let be more focus. Can you provide us the Api Resource code? can you show us the data before and after filtered?

Answer (score 0):

To actually get results you should use some function that gets data from database, for example `get`, `first` (depends whether you want to get multiple rows or only first row). Now you only prepare query that should be executed but you never execute it, so yo should change line:

```
$bonus = Filterer::apply($request, $size, $bonus);
```

into

```
$bonus = Filterer::apply($request, $size, $bonus);
$bonus = $bonus->get();
```

to execute query and get results.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the input into array, here I'm using `explode()`
and then I loop the converted array and use `%%` to search the `providers`. Hope it will help!

```
if ($filters->has('provider') && trim($filters->input('provider')) != "") {
            $bonus_list->whereHas('bonusCompany', function ($query) use ($filters) {

                $providers = explode(',', (trim($filters->input('provider'), '[]')));

                foreach ($providers as $key => $provider) {
                    if ($key == 0) {
                        $query->where('providers', 'LIKE', ['%' . trim($provider) . '%']);
                    } else {
                        $query->orwhere('providers', 'LIKE', ['%' . trim($provider) . '%']);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```