# Search for products by ship to country

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table of `countries`, which has this field:

```
title: string
```

I have a table of `products`, which has these fields:

```
title,
description
...
ship_to: longText
```

The format of `ship_to` is like this, for example a product can be shipped to three countries with `IDs` of `10`, `20`, `30`

```
ship_to: {[10,20,30]}
```

Now, what I want to do is to filter products by countries that they can be shipped to. So, for example, I give an array of 10,20 (ids of countries), and I would like to find products that ship to at least one of these countries.

But I cannot come up with anything that would be efficient. I was thinking about foreach loop with `orWhereIn('ship_to', $givenArrayOfCountryIds)`

or something like that, but I see that it would become a bottleneck of this filter query as the time goes on.

How can I fix my database design or maybe there is a hidden Laravel eloquent function for this? I couldnt find any that would complete this task.

This is a bit of code I wrote before realizing that this is not gonna work:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Model\Filters\Product;

use App\Model\Contracts\AbstractClasses\Filter;

class ShipsTo extends Filter
{
    protected function applyFilter($builder)
    {
        $filterName = $this->filterName();
        $shipsTo = request()->$filterName;
        if ($shipsTo && count($shipsTo) > 0) {
            return $builder->whereHas('countries', function ($query) use ($shipsTo) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $shipsTo);
            });
        }
        return $builder;
    }
}
```

I use pipeline to combine multiple filters in one. This is code that calls pipeline:

```php
public function search($term, $limit)
{
    $builder = Product::select([
        'id', 
        'title',
        'image',
        'price',
        'sale_price'
    ])->active();

    $builder = app(Pipeline::class)
        ->send($builder)
        ->through([
            ShipsTo::class,
        ])
        ->thenReturn();

    return $builder->paginate($limit);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: why  haven't  you create a Many to Many relations from products and country?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188529/laravel-eloquent-query-json-column-with-where-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that the best way to solve it is a many to many relation from products and countries. In order to obtain it, create a new table on your database, like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products_countries(
   product_id int not null, /* or the domain of product table primary key */
   country_id int not null, /* or the domain of country table primary key */
   primary key(product_id, country_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product(id), //or the product table primary key
   FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES Country(id), //or the product country primary key
)
```

and than on the Product model:

```php
public function countries(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country');
}
```

and than on the Country model:

```php
public function products(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Comment: I tried this at first, but then realised that if I have 40k products and each of them sends to 200 different countries it is 2million rows.

Comment: using SQL indexes will improve the efficiency, also caching could help, and i think this will be way more efficient that looping a whole array, but it'a personal opinion